# Unexpected backwards incompatability in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have a dev environment running sqlite 3.7.16.2 and a production environment running sqlite 3.7.9 and I am running into some unexpected backwards incompatability.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
sqlite> select * from calls;
ID|calldate|calltype
1|2013-10-01|monthly
1|2013-11-01|3 month
1|2013-12-01|monthly
2|2013-07-11|monthly
2|2013-08-11|monthly
2|2013-09-11|3 month
2|2013-10-11|monthly
2|2013-11-11|monthly
3|2013-04-22|monthly
3|2013-05-22|monthly
3|2013-06-22|3 month
3|2013-07-22|monthly
4|2013-10-04|monthly
4|2013-11-04|3 month
4|2013-12-04|monthly
5|2013-10-28|monthly
5|2013-11-28|monthly
```

With the newer version of sqlite (3.7.16.2) I can use this:

`SELECT ID, MIN(calldate), calltype FROM calls WHERE calldate > date('NOW') GROUP BY ID;`

which gives me:

```
ID|MIN(calldate)|calltype
1|2013-11-01|3 month
2|2013-11-11|monthly
4|2013-11-04|3 month
5|2013-10-28|monthly
```

However when I run this same code on the older version of sqlite (3.7.9) I get this:

```
ID|MIN(calldate)|calltype
1|2013-11-01|monthly
2|2013-11-11|monthly
4|2013-11-04|monthly
5|2013-10-28|monthly
```

I looked through the changes [here](https://www.sqlite.org/formatchng.html), but could not figure out why this is still happening. Any suggestions on how to work around this or how to rewrite my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an extension that was added in [SQLite 3.7.11](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_11.html).

In standard SQL, it is not allowed to use columns that appear neither in the `GROUP BY` clause nor are wrapped in an aggregate function.
(SQLite accepts this silently for compatibility with MySQL, but returns the data from some random record in the group.)

To get other columns from a record with the minimum value, you have to search the minimum values for each group first, and then to join these with the original table:

```sql
SELECT calls.ID,
       calls.calldate,
       calls.calltype
FROM calls
JOIN (SELECT ID,
             MIN(calldate) AS calldate
      FROM calls
      WHERE calldate > date('now')
      GROUP BY ID
     ) AS earliest
ON calls.ID       = earliest.ID       AND
   calls.calldate = earliest.calldate
```